# Big table and composite key

Tags: database-design

Big table records are identified by a composite key, what are the components of this key? And what is the benefit of making it composite?

Comment: Which key is "this key"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you asking what "component of a composite key" means?

Answer (score 1):

For very large tables (row wise), giving each individual row a unique id would be limited by the data type in which you represent the unique id. For example, if you are storing the unique id as a basic int32, what happens when you have more than 2147483647 entries (max value of int32)?

I'll use an example of Amazon, trying to track which items a customer has viewed. You could imagine a table called "items_customer_has_viewed." For a single customer, it wouldn't be a problem to have a unique id for this table. Maybe a customer only views 50 items on amazon in a year, and that database could stay small for quite a while, staying under the 2147483647 limit. However, when you have millions of users, the value of the unique id will get too large.

You could choose to store your unique id as a string or blob, but that would slow the database down and require additional computation.

The solution is to use a composite key. Instead of having a unique id that identifies a single "view," or a "item a customer has viewed," you identify that "view" with two foreign keys (together, forming one composite primary key). Now, you only need less than 2147483647 customers and less than 2147483647 items, and you'll be fine. You won't have problems storing the id.

Comment: For this reason, most databases will allow very much larger numeric data types, so you do not need to resort to strings, blobs, or composite keys. For example, PostgreSQL sequences will generate up to 2^63-1 by default, with the big integer type ranging up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. The numeric type will handle up to 131,072 digits before the decimal point. So if you need to use one of those tricks to be able to store that many rows, you've made an extremely poor choice of database.